# Created several coded ui tests, but they don't show in test explorer unless manually opened

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

I have created several coded ui tests in visual studio 2017 and then attached them to test cases in tfs. I can only see the test method if I manually open the project. Should I be able to see all my test methods from all my projects listed in test explorer. For example I have projects for....create...edit...delete. They have created project folders in my output location and the .csproj file is in this folder. Is there any way I can get visual studio to recognize the test methods that are in the different project folders, or is this not possible? I can run them individually, but I want to run them as a group and in the future run them overnight. Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated as I am fairly new to automated testing. I have searched the questions and although there are many questions about coded ui, none really fit what I am looking for. If this question has been answered before I apologize.

Thanks
Russell

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
It is possible that Test Explorer should show your all test cases. All you have to do is open the Solution file which contains all the projects. After building the solution you can view your all Test Methods in test explorer.

You can run test cases Individually and in a Group also directly from the test explorer by creating playlists in test explorer or by selecting multiple test cases.

If you want to run it from the TFS test cases then you need to configure following things setup first:

- Linking of automated Test Method with manual ones in TFS
- Build Server
- Microsoft Test Manager (MTM)
- Test Controller
- Test Agent
- A Database if you are using for test Data

[image]

For more checkout [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mathew_aniyan/2009/05/26/coded-ui-test-from-microsoft-test-lab-manager/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful and clear. I had to build a new solution first (as I had not created one), but once I done that I right clicked and added the projects I wanted. Very simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all the test methods together in visual studio from different projects, you have to add all the projects in a single solution(If you have done it, good!).

Now you will be able to see all the test cases altogether. But if you need to separate them by a particular category(if your case "create", "edit", "delete" you can use unit test attribute ' [TestCategory("categoryName")] '

E.g. : If you have a test method name RegisterWithNewUser() then you have to do

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Create")
    public void RegisterWithNewUser()
    {
    //test method actions
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("edit")]
    public void CodedUITestMethod2()
    {
        //test method actions
    }

    [TestMethod, TestCategory("delete")]
    public void CodedUITestMethod3()
    {
        //test method actions

    }
```

After this you will see in test explorer something like this

[image]

Don't forget to check the checkbox Traits, there are other group by options also present which are helpful in your case.

[image]